# Does a track run in a fragmented MP4 have to start with a key frame?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, media-source

I'm ingesting an RTMP stream and converting it to a fragmented MP4 file in JavaScript. It took a week of work but I'm almost finished with this task. I'm generating a valid `ftyp` atom, `moov` atom, and `moof` atom and the first frame of the video actually plays (with audio) before it goes into an infinite buffering with no errors listed in `chrome://media-internals`

Plugging the video into `ffprobe`, I get an error similar to:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x558559198080] Failed to add index entry
    Last message repeated 368 times
[h264 @ 0x55855919b300] Invalid NAL unit size (-619501801 > 966).
[h264 @ 0x55855919b300] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
```

This led me on a massive hunt for data alignment issues or invalid byte offsets in my `tfhd` and `trun` atoms, however no matter where I looked or how I sliced the data, I couldn't find any problems in the `moof` atom.

I then took the original FLV file and converted it to an MP4 in `ffmpeg` with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Videos/rtmp/big_buck_bunny.flv -c copy -ss 5 -t 10 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov+faststart test.mp4
```

I opened both the MP4 I was creating and the MP4 output by `ffmpeg` in an atom parsing file and compared the two:

[image: Comparing MP4 files with MP4A]

The first thing that jumped out at me was the `ffmpeg`-generated file has multiple video samples per `moof`. Specifically, every `moof` started with 1 key frame, then contained all difference frames until the next key frame (which was used as the start of the following `moof` atom)

Contrast this with how I'm generating my MP4. I create a `moof` atom every time an FLV `VIDEODATA` packet arrives. This means my `moof` may not contain a key frame (and usually doesn't)

Could this be why I'm having trouble? Or is there something else I'm missing?

The video files in question can be downloaded here:

- [`ffmpeg`-generated file: `test.mp4`](http://files.stevendesu.com/test.mp4)
- [manually-generated file: `invalid-nal-size.mp4`](http://files.stevendesu.com/invalid-nal-size.mp4)

Another issue I noticed was `ffmpeg`'s prolific use of `base_data_offset` in the `tfhd` atom. However when I tried tracking the total number of bytes appended and setting the `base_data_offset` myself, I got an error in Chrome along the lines of: "MSE doesn't support base_data_offset". Per the ISO/IEC 14996-10 spec:

> If not provided, the base-data-offset for the first track in the movie fragment is the position of the first byte of the enclosing Movie Fragment Box, and for second and subsequent track fragments, the default is the end of the data defined by the preceding fragment.

This wording leads me to believe that the `data_offset` in the first `trun` atom should be equal to the size of the `moof` atom and the `data_offset` in the second `trun` atom should be `0` (0 bytes from the end of the data defined by the preceding fragment). However when I tried this I got an error that the video data couldn't be parsed. What ***did*** lead to data that could be parsed was the length of the `moof` atom plus the total length of the first track (as if the base offset were the first byte of the enclosing `moof` box, same as the first track)

Comment: What is the software in the picture you named?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the moof does not need to start with a key frame. The file you are generating produces invalid NALUs size errors, Because it has invalid nal sizes. Every nal (in the mdat) must have the size prepended to it. Looking at your file, the first 4 bytes after the mdat is `0x21180C68` which is WAY too large to be a valid size.

Comment: I have the audio track first, and the video track second. `0x21180C68` is AAC data, not H.264 data

Comment: Going to mark this as correct since "No, the moof does not need to start with a key frame." accurately answers the question. But the following sentences are incorrect (my NAL sizes were valid, `0x21180C68` wasn't a NAL size since it was audio data and not video data). The reason my video was not playing was due to my `traf` having a 0 duration. The misleading error message was due to a bug in FFMPEG. I ended up reading the entire FFMPEG source code to figure that one out.

Comment: @stevendesu Thank you for the clarification. Did you mean that you used flag default‐sample‐duration‐present in your Track Fragment Header Box and default_sample_duration was set to 0?

Comment: @Hong I don’t have the original files anymore or remember precisely, but if I were to guess it was a combination of having a default sample duration of zero (as you suggested) and not overriding this default in the Track Fragment Run (trun) box (either via not setting the sample duration present bit or by setting the sample duration to zero)